# Query Android SMS Log

Tags: java, android, sms, mms, telephony

Is there a way to access and query the android SMS/MMS log? To clarify, the SMS/MMS Log is all the SMS/MMS messages sent by the host phone. It can be aquired by reading a cursor to the message inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I believe the only way you can do that is to send and log the text messages through your own program.  The built-in Messaging app (`com.android.mms`) does not seem to expose its log history.

Comment: What about a cursor to the SMS Inbox.